# Controlling my Computer via Remote Controller

Tags: remote, remote-control

Is it possible to control my Computer using a Remote Control device (something similar to our TV Remotes) ? So that I don't have to get up from my sofa or bed to turn of my computer or switch it on or to play, pause , stop a movie. I am using windows XP SP3 PRO 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft used to make MCE remote controls, which came with a USB IR receiver, but they seem to have stopped production.  They are specifically designed for Windows Media Centre, but there is other third party media player and system software that can be used with them.

[image: Microsoft MCE Remote Control]

You may be able to find old stock on eBay and there are many other third-party alternatives.  Just search Google for 'MCE Remote'.

Answer (score 3):

My personal choice was an [AGPtek Rii Mini PC Keyboard with Touchpad.](http://www.buy.com/prod/2-4g-wireless-cordless-candyboard-rii-mini-pc-keyboard-with-touchpad/q/loc/101/219450935.html)  Works well with my HTPC, gives me full control of the PC, and even has a laser pointer so I can mess with the cats.  Internal battery lasts about a month for us (your mileage may vary) and charges via USB.  Max range is 10-14 feet, line of sight.

[image: AGPtek Rii Mini PC Keyboard with Touchpad]

Comment: How much did it cost you ?

Comment: Can you see your mouse pointer from 14 feet away ?

Comment: @SpongeBobSquarePants, whether you can see your mouse or not is an entirely unrelated question. With a large enough display set with some zoom if necessary, it should be fine though.

Comment: @SpongeBob SquarePants I think I paid roughly $40.00 for it (used the buy.com link because they had the lowest price 6 months ago). With my 42 inch TV I can make out my enlarged pointer from the far side of my living room.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you get a wireless Keyboard and mouse?
You get the functionality you want and a lot lot more.

Comment: I want something which I can hold in my palm , wireless keyboards are very big for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00224ZDFY)? It simulates keyboard presses so you should be able to set it up to do whatever you want and according to the description you can control the mouse with it.

Comment: Thanks that looks awesome :D .Please correct typo: "tot he"  to  "to the"

Comment: ^already done, I noticed that one immediately after I posted.